# insert a <br> after each . in the value of the database

Tags: php, database, echo

The value display in the database shows all value in the same paragraph. I want to insert a `<br>` in my echo code so that any . (dot) is detected it will imply a `<br>`.

Below is my code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "   ". $row["news"]. "<br>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below snippet for the same.

```
$str = str_replace(".",".<br/>",$str);
```

It will replace every dot(.) with `.<br/>`

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

**Syntax**:

```
str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] ) : mixed
```

In your example,

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row["news"] = str_replace(".",".<br/>",$row["news"]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: another question suppose i do not imply the str_replace code. How can i echo and display the exact form that are inserted in the database. Like paragraph , bullet points change paragraph

Comment: You can use `nl2br`. Here is the usage [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for the same

Comment: Do u have any idea how could I imply this in my code above please??

Comment: When you will use `echo` to display content as it as use like `echo nl2br($yourContent);` and please check its official doc for the same.